# How to secure and limit access to Web Services runing on AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, security

I have a set of webservices in the backend of a Typo3 website and I need to get info via AJAX, however the information that I get costs the company money so I have to assure that only legitimate queries are being processed.

I though about adding some rule that the AJAX call is only processed when the call comes from www.example.com/typo3/backend.php but I am not sure if that is even possible.

So what are the general option to authentificate via AJAX and jQuery

Comment: Check the referrer on the server, but that can be spoofed. Use sessions and restrict number of calls.

Comment: Any security has to be implemented on the webservices/server side. You can disable CORS on the server to prevent any calls from external domains. Or, if webservices can be called cross-domain, then the most common way to authenticate is to issue API keys and create a validation signature. It's a very broad subject, too broad to be answered in this forum. You can read Amazons WS authenication standard: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html#signing-request-intro . Not sure it this will help you.